# Running google chrome puppeteer on Vultr, Digital Ocean, Heroku, Or GAE

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, heroku, digital-ocean

I have tried to run Google Chrome puppeteer on Heroku, GAE flex, Digital Ocean, and Vultr but at the route where I use puppeteer the instance just hangs until it errors with 502. I'm using this simple code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    (async() => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://example.com');
        await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

        browser.close();
        res.send('screen grabbed');
    })();
});

module.exports = router;
```

I know puppeteer works with node 6 now but I'm setting `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "puppeteer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy --version dev"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta11",
    "puppeteer": "^0.10.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

In Vultr Ubuntu 16.04 x64 I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>
> /root/mysite/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-497674/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved by making sure the following dependencies for puppeteer were installed if not :

Installed all the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Then pass args to the puppeteer launch command like so:

```
(async() => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://example.com');
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
res.send('screen grabbed');
browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Made it work for me in Ubuntu 16.04 on a DigitalOcean server.

Comment: do you have an example repo with docker?

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above answer but no luck in DigitaOcean Ubuntu droplet.

So I installed **`google-chrome-stable`** in the droplet, that works.

1. Add Key:

   ```sh
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Set repository:

   ```sh
   echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
3. Install package:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

Comment: I googled for a solution everywhere for the whole day and this is what I needed. Thank you!